# Can't Open Geodatabase in QGIS on External Harddrive

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase

I have a geodatabase that opens in QGIS fine on my internal drive, but not on my external.

They both have the same permissions. The internal drive is formatted as APFS, and the external is ExFAT.

I'm using the NYC [LION](https://www1.nyc.gov/site/planning/data-maps/open-data/dwn-lion.page) dataset for reference.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want a workaround, such as converting the geodatabase to another format? Are you trying to edit the geodatabase, or only view it?

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: @csk I am both editing and viewing a few databases that are too large for my internal drive.

Comment: @GreyHippo "There is no data found at the path"

Comment: Are you using Windows?  This article (https://lifehacker.com/5927185/use-the-exfat-file-system-and-never-format-your-external-drive-again) says that the external drive has to be formatted to exFAT on a Windows box before it can read it inside Windows.

Comment: Try to open some other file in some other program to make sure your are reading the external drive correctly.  Put a shapefile on the external drive and see if it can read it using QGIS.